# How to add the current timestamp to output in webpack4 if running in watch mode with minimal output

Tags: webpack, continuous-integration, webpack-4

When you do CI and have a little window open with webpack watching your files sometimes it is hard to see if webpack has detected your changes yet (windows 10 here).

So I reduced the output with --display=minimal. But now the output is just "33 modules". All look the same.

I want to add a timestamp to the output so I can distinguish them.

There was a solution for webpack3 which will give you a DeprecationWarning in webpack4:

```
Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
```

So please do **not** use this:

```
--do not use this in webpack4--  

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    this.plugin('done',function(){/*...*/})
  ]
}

--do not use this in webpack4--
```

I miss a migration path.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for posting this, it seems pretty useful. It would be even better if you split it up into a question (which states the problem) and an answer (which explains the solution). It's perfectly acceptable for you to answer your own question, and as a bonus you'll also be able to receive more reputation if you split this into a question and and answer :)

Comment: @schu34 Took me some time but now I see your point. Thanks for telling me. I was too focussed on my stuff. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the solution for webpack4:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    function() {
      this.hooks.done.tap('BuildStatsPlugin', function() {
        console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
      });
    }
  ]
};
```

So if you now do...

```
webpack --watch --display=minimal
```

... whenever you change one of your files webpack will recompile and only add two lines to the console output:

```
webpack is watching the files…

22:05:34
   33 modules
22:16:04
   33 modules
```